# IE not calling lifecycle hooks or filling @Input until change detected?

Tags: internet-explorer-11, angular

I'm using beta.0 because [this outstanding bug](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6501) prevents angular 2 from working in IE in beta.1 and beta.2.

Relevant code from SearchBar.ts

```
@Component({
  selector : 'search-bar',
  templateUrl: 'views/searchbar.html'
})
export class SearchBar {
  private history: SearchHistoryEntry[] = [];

  @Output() onHistory = new EventEmitter();

  constructor() {
    this.history = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('SearchHistory')) || [];
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    // The constructor doesn't have @Outputs initialized yet. Emit from this
    // life cycle hook instead to be sure they're received on the other side
    debugger;
    this.onHistory.emit(this.history);
  }
}
```

Relevant code from home.html

```
<search-bar (onHistory)="SearchBarHistory($event)"></search-bar>
```

Relevant code from home.ts

```
SearchBarHistory(history: SearchHistoryEntry[]) {
  debugger;
  this.history = history;
}
```

In Chrome this works just fine. The SearchBar's constructor correctly reads from `localStorage`, in `ngOnInit` it emits to my Home component who receives it, it's stored locally and the UI bindings tied to `history` update to show the information as it all should.

In IE 11 this does not work. `ngOnInit` won't run until I click inside my search bar. It seems that any `@Input` or lifecycle hook (specifically I've tested `ngOnInit`, `ngAfterContentInit`, and `ngAfterViewInit` and they all behave the same) doesn't run until the component's change detection is triggered. If I refresh the page then it runs exactly like Chrome where no interaction is required for `@Input`s or lifecycle hooks to be called and my history goes through and gets bound like it should.

I think this is a bug of the beta but in the mean time is there anything I can do to make it work the first time without an interaction or page refresh?

Comment: Writing this example in typescript has no involvement with the problem. In the end, when it's compiled to JS, the problem still exists. I'm going to remove the typescript tag.

Answer (score 2):

I am having the same issue I tried it to resolve by forcing detectChanges like:

```
import {Injectable,ApplicationRef, NgZone} from '@angular/core';
@Injectable()
export class IeHackService {

constructor(
    private _appRef: ApplicationRef,
    private _zone: NgZone) {}

private isIe() {
    let ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
    let msie = ua.indexOf('MSIE ');
    if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./)) // If Internet Explorer, return version number
        return true;
    return false;
}

onComponentLoadInIe() {
    if (this.isIe()) {
        this._zone.run(() => setTimeout(() => this._appRef.tick(), 5));
    }
}
}
```

Then in Every Route component that uses Lifecycle Hooks  I called

```
   constructor(private dialogService: ModalDialogService,ieHackService: IeHackService) {
    ieHackService.onComponentLoadInIe();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well, I used a workaround to automatically refresh the page if the bug occurs, hoping that [the bug](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6867) will eventually be solved.

It's very ugly, but for now it works at least.

```js
declare var Modernizr: any;

@Component({
  selector : 'search-bar',
  templateUrl: 'views/searchbar.html'
})
export class SearchBar {
  private history: SearchHistoryEntry[] = [];

  @Output() onHistory = new EventEmitter();

  ie11hack: boolean = true;

  constructor() {
    this.history = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('SearchHistory')) || [];

    if (!Modernizr.es6collections || navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("safari") !== -1) {

      setTimeout(() => {
        if (this.ie11hack) {
          window.location.reload();
        }
      }, 500);
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    ie11hack = false;
    // The constructor doesn't have @Outputs initialized yet. Emit from this
    // life cycle hook instead to be sure they're received on the other side
    debugger;
    this.onHistory.emit(this.history);
  }
}
```

### Edit, a less ugly partial fix:

The issues is (I think) caused by using a direct url rather then using the angular router (javascript).
If you want your website to work if people enter their url manually then you still need the above hack, but otherwise you may do what I did below (you may want to do that anyway).

I changed this:

```
<!-- html -->
<a href="#/objects/objectthingy/{{myObject.id}}" class="my-object-class">
```

To this:

```
<!-- html -->
<a href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="openMyObject(myObject.id)" class="my-object-class">

// typescript
openMyObject(objectId: number) {
    this.router.navigate(['/Objects', 'ObjectThingy', { id: objectId}]);
}
```

and `ngAfterViewInit` method was called again.